# Problem showing image from a database with JSF via a Servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2

***EDIT:** The reason for this issue was due to bug unrelated to the servlet.*

I'm working on a JSF2/JPA/EJB3 project that enables users to upload photos of themselves and stores them in a database. Loading images from the database is made possible with a servlet. There is however a problem; when changing the picture and posting the page, the image goes blank. The servlet doesn't seem to be called.

Web page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:graphicImage value="image?fileId=#{bean.currentUser.photo.id}"/>
    <3rd party file upload component (primeFaces)/>
    <h:commandButton value="post"/>
</h:form>
```

Servlet mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xdin.competence.jsf.util.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/image/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet:

```
@ManagedBean
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.
    @EJB private UserBean userBean;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Long fileId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("fileId"));
        if (fileId == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
        }
        UserFile photo = userBean.findUserFile(fileId);
        // Init servlet response.
        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(photo.getFileData().length));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + photo.getFilename() + "\"");

        // Prepare streams.
        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            // Open streams.
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(photo.getFileData()), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Write file contents to response.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            // Gently close streams.
            close(output);
            close(input);
        }
    }

    private static void close(Closeable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail it.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

My guess is that doGet in ImageServlet is only called on Get. Forcing a new GET with faces-redirect=true works, but is it possible to make the servlet work on POST aswell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to think that images are downloaded as part of the HTTP response containing the HTML page containing the `<img>` elements. This is not true. The browser obtains the HTML page, parses the HTML structure, encounters the `<img>` element and fires **separate** HTTP requests for each of them. It is *always* GET. The same applies to CSS/JS and other resources. Install a HTTP request debugger tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and check the *Net* panel.

The actual problem is likely that the URL as definied in `src` attribute is wrong. You're using a context-relative path (i.e. no leading slash and no domain in the `src` attribute, it's fully dependent on the current request URL -the one in browser address bar). Probably the HTML page get posted to a different context/folder which caused that the image becomes unreachable from that point. Try using an absolute path or a domain-relative path.

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{request.contextPath}/image?fileId=#{bean.currentUser.photo.id}" />
```

If still in vain, then have a closer look at Firebug's analysis.

Comment: As it turns out, it was a bug in my controller which caused currentUser to be outdated; value="image?fileId=..." works in this specific case because the web page lies in the root. Thank you for the answer still, I was a abit confused about how images were fetched after a post.